# How can I read a specific line of TXT file in my computer using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have database.txt in C:\ containing data line by line.

How can I get a specific nth line of TXT so that embed texts between lines from data?

example of database.txt is :

```
Real Madrid
Barcelona
Bayern Munich
Manchester United
```

what I want to write is :

```
HAHA 1
Real Madrid
HOHO
HAHA 2
Barcelona
HOHO
HAHA 3
Bayern Munich
HOHO
HAHA 4
Manchester United
HOHO
```

Can I get specific line with embedding given text by specific pattern??

Thanks.

Comment: What JavaScript do you have so what? What environment are you running it in? Node? WSH? A browser? How are you reading the file?

Comment: I'm trying to write a source code based on JavaScript in html file in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with javascript from a browser since it does not allow to read files from the disk. You can do it by making an XmlHttpRequest to a aspx or ashx that returns the file as string. Then split the string on newline \n and take the line you want by index.

Comment: "...does not allow to read files from the disk" - only for unprivileged javascript running in a browser - there are lots of scenarios where that is not the case (although it would have helped if fiverules had told us what scenario he/she is referring to).

Comment: That is true. Above answer applies to unprivileged javascript